# Returning Data with $.ajax VB.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, json

```
<WebMethod()> Public Shared Function gtet() As String
    ...
    Dim GET = uClass.GetSets(dbuser, dbparam1)
    ...
End Function
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    data = { };
    var jsondata = $.toJSON(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "index.aspx/gtet",
        data: jsondata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr)
        {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                         "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        },
        success: function (cget)
        {
            alert(cget);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            window.location.reload();

        }
    });
}
```

Am I doing this right? I need to pull the string from Dim GET

Comment: (unrelated) why are you setting the "Content-type" header in the beforeSend when you specify it in the "contentType" option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the json as a parameter.

```
data: {
    "json": jsondata
},
```

Also, make sure your webmethod is returning valid json.